# How to Use ArrayAdapter with Multiple Textview columns in listView Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.android, android-arrayadapter

I have listview with 4 columns like ItemLookupCode,Quantity,Description,Price

I am adding full code i am sorting list on button click.

**i have issue in following Populate() to call 4 textview**

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.PriceCheckList);
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            foreach (crItem item in listObject)
            {
                list.Add(item.ItemLookupCode);
                list.Add(Convert.ToString(item.Quantity));
                list.Add(item.Description);
                list.Add(Convert.ToString(item.Price));
            }
           spacecrafts = list.ToArray(); 
            this.InitializeViews();
            this.SortData(ascending);
            this.ascending = !ascending;
       }
            SortBtnItemLookupCode.Click += sortBtn_Click;
void sortBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SortData(ascending);
            this.ascending = !ascending;
        }
        private void InitializeViews()
        {
            listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
            SortBtnItemLookupCode = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.SortBtnItemLookupCode);
        }


 private void Populate()
        {
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.PriceCheckListTemplate, Resource.Id.lblItemLookupCode, spacecrafts);
                listView.SetAdapter(adapter);
        }

private void SortData(bool asc)
        {
            if (asc)
            {
                Array.Sort(spacecrafts);
            }
            else
            {
                Array.Reverse(spacecrafts);
            }
                Populate();
            }
        }
```

I want to assign all above 4 object to Textview but currently ArrayAdapter accept only one Textview like i have use below Resource.Id.lblItemLookupCode but How i can assign 4 object to 4 columns Textview in ArrayAdapter

Help much appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try create model class to define data for the listView's item, then customize a custom Adapter to populate the data.

Check the code:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        string[] items = new string[] { "Vegetables", "Fruits", "Flower Buds", "Legumes", "Bulbs", "Tubers" };
        List<CustomModel> list = new List<CustomModel>();
        //add data
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(list);

        ListView listview_ = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listview_);
        listview_.SetAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

public class CustomModel
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class CustomAdapter : BaseAdapter<CustomModel>
{
    List<CustomModel> list = new List<CustomModel>();
    public _Adapter(List<CustomModel> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public override CustomModel this[int position]
    {
        get
        {
            return list[position];
        }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return list.Count;
        }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var view = convertView;
        view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout1, parent, false);

        //specify value to the each textView
        var textview = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text_1);
        textview.Text = list[position].Value1;
        ...

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: My issue in below method.

private void Populate()
        {

      ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.PriceCheckListTemplate, Resource.Id.lblItemLookupCode, spacecrafts);

           listView.SetAdapter(adapter);
  }

  **//i have issue here need to add more textvew in ArrayAdapter  like Resource.Id.lblItemLookupCode,Resource.Id.lblDescription, Resource.Id.lblQty....,spacecrafts);**

Comment: The ArrayAdapter doesn't support to receive multi textView source. Try creating Custom row layouts and referece the layout view in BaseAdapter's `GetView` method. Check the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/list-view/customizing-appearance#creating-a-custom-row-layout

Comment: @ Jarvan Zhang solution not working i am update and add full code in my question. please check and guide me thanks

Comment: The `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, IList<T> objects)` method only can be used to display one textView in the item. If you want to display multi views in each item, please create a custom adapter instead.